# Set column E from column B when a value from D exists in A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, data-entry

When a value entered in D exists in A, E and F should be populated from B and C respectively.
So, when "*New York*" is pasted in column D, E for that row should be set to 33 and F should be set to 3.
Values in A and D are unordered and column A has more rows than column D.

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tokyo | 30 | 0 | *New York* | *33* | *3* |
| Istanbul | 31 | 1 | *Tokyo* | *30* | *0* |
| Liverpool | 32 | 2 |  |  |  |
| New York | 33 | 3 |  |  |  |

I'm actually using LibreOffice for this, but I could switch to Excel if this can be solved better through Excel features. Cheers!

Comment: What formula have you used so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the XLOOKUP function:

E1: `=IF(ISBLANK($D1),"",XLOOKUP($D1,$A$1:$A$4,$B$1:$B$4))`

F1: `=IF(ISBLANK($D1),"",XLOOKUP($D1,$A$1:$A$4,$C$1:$C$4))`

Copy the two formulas across to rows 2-4.

Answer (score 1):

Using Libreoffice calc

E1: `=IF(ISBLANK($D1),"", INDEX(B$1:B$4,MATCH(D1,A$1:A$4,0),0))`

F1: `=IF(ISBLANK($D1),"", INDEX(C$1:C$4,MATCH(E1,B$1:B$4,0),0))`